# Is there a way to convert nltk featuresets into a scipy.sparse array?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, scikits

I'm trying to use scikit.learn which needs numpy/scipy arrays for input.
The featureset generated in nltk consists of unigram and bigram frequencies. I could do it manually, but that'll be a lot of effort. So wondering if there's a solution i've overlooked.

Comment: Why can't you take the feature values and simply put them into a numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, but note that scikit-learn can do *n*-gram frequency counting itself. Assuming word-level *n*-grams:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, WordNGramAnalyzer
v = CountVectorizer(analyzer=WordNGramAnalyzer(min_n=1, max_n=2))
X = v.fit_transform(files)
```

where `files` is a list of strings or file-like objects. After this, `X` is a scipy.sparse matrix of raw frequency counts.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Perkins did a a bridge for training NLTK classifiers using scikit-learn classifiers that does exactly that here is the source:

https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer/blob/master/nltk_trainer/classification/sci.py

The package import lines should be updated if you are using version 0.9+.