# Reorganizing output data in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, vector, transpose, sparse-matrix

I need to create sparse vectors and I would like to try it using `python`.
I have all of the data needed already to create the vectors, so my task is basically reformatting/rearranging the information that I have.

The input file I have is a 5GB file with 3 tab-separated columns, for example:

```
abandonment-n   about+n-the+v-know-v    1
abandonment-n   above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v   1
abandonment-n   after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1
abandonment-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 1
cake-n  against+n-the+vg-restv  1
cake-n  as+n-a+vd-require-v 1
cake-n  as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1
cake-n  as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 2
dog-n   as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7
dog-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 5
```

My desired output is the following

```
2   7
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   2
7   5
```

where, the first line specifies the dimensions (essentially unique row // col)
and the second line begins the actual matrix, in sparse format.

I think the most effective way to do this would be in `python`. 
However, as I already have calculated he corresponding weights of the data, I do not think that the classes in `numpy` or for vectors, such as found [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049154/python-numpy-vector-math) are necessary in this case.
So, does anyone have any insight how I can begin to tackle this rearranging problem in python?

The first thing that I have thought to do is open the file and split the elements in a dictionary:
like this:

```
mydict = {}
with open("sample_outputDM_ALL_COOC", 'r') as infile_A:
    for line in infile_A:
        lines_splitted = line.split()
        lemma = lines_splitted[0]
        feat = lines_splitted[1]
        weight = lines_splitted[2]
        mydict = [lemma], float(weight)
        #print mydict

        for x in mydict:
            if lemma == lemma:
                print weight + "\t"
            else:
                pass
```

I have been working very hard on solving this problem and I still have not been able to.
What I have done until now is input all of the variables into a dictionary and I am able to print the each individual lemma and each individual weight per row.

However, I need to have all of weights corresponding to a given lemma in the same row.
I have tried the `groupby` variable, but I am not sure that it is the best option for this case. 
I believe that the solution if the for `if else` statement, but I cant figure out how to link the two.

Thus, the method should be along the lines of: for every `target`, print `freq` of `slotfiller` in one row for each unique `target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for homework? If not, check out the tools available in [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) or a mixture of [scikits.learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) and [Python NLTK](http://nltk.org/) ([e.g. this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394257/is-there-a-way-to-convert-nltk-featuresets-into-a-scipy-sparse-array)).

**Added**
Based on the comment and re-reading the question, I can also imagine using Pandas.DataFrame to accomplish this, but I am not sure if it will be satisfactory given the size of the data. One option would be to load the data in multiple chunks, since it seems to be parallelizable on unique items of the first column. (See my [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046386/constructing-sparse-vectors-from-data-using-dataset-in-python/20050186#comment29863370_20050186) for more on that).

```
def sparse_vec(df):
    return (df['Col3'].values[None,:],)

# Obviously these would be chunk-specific, and you'd need to do
# another pass to get the global sum of unique ids from Col1 and the
# global max of the number of unique rows-per-id.
n_cols = len(df.Col2.unique())
n_rows = len(df.Col1.unique())


vecs = df.groupby("Col1").apply(sparse_vec)
print vecs
```

Using this on the sample data you gave, in IPython, I see this:

```
In [17]: data = """
   ....: abandonment-n   about+n-the+v-know-v    1
   ....: abandonment-n   above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v   1
   ....: abandonment-n   after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1
   ....: abandonment-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 1
   ....: cake-n  against+n-the+vg-restv  1
ake-   ....: cake-n  as+n-a+vd-require-v 1
   ....: cake-n  as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1
   ....: cake-n  as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 2
   ....: dog-n   as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7
dog-   ....: dog-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 5"""

In [18]: data
Out[18]: '\nabandonment-n   about+n-the+v-know-v    1\nabandonment-n   above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v   1\nabandonment-n   after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1\nabandonment-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 1\ncake-n  against+n-the+vg-restv  1\ncake-n  as+n-a+vd-require-v 1\ncake-n  as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1\ncake-n  as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 2\ndog-n   as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7\ndog-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 5'

In [19]: data.split("\n")
Out[19]:
['',
 'abandonment-n   about+n-the+v-know-v    1',
 'abandonment-n   above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v   1',
 'abandonment-n   after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1',
 'abandonment-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 1',
 'cake-n  against+n-the+vg-restv  1',
 'cake-n  as+n-a+vd-require-v 1',
 'cake-n  as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1',
 'cake-n  as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 2',
 'dog-n   as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7',
 'dog-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 5']

In [20]: data_lines = [x for x in data.split("\n") if x]

In [21]: data_lines
Out[21]:
['abandonment-n   about+n-the+v-know-v    1',
 'abandonment-n   above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v   1',
 'abandonment-n   after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1',
 'abandonment-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 1',
 'cake-n  against+n-the+vg-restv  1',
 'cake-n  as+n-a+vd-require-v 1',
 'cake-n  as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1',
 'cake-n  as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 2',
 'dog-n   as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7',
 'dog-n   as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n 5']

In [22]: split_lines = [x.split() for x in data_lines]

In [23]: split_lines
Out[23]:
[['abandonment-n', 'about+n-the+v-know-v', '1'],
 ['abandonment-n', 'above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v', '1'],
 ['abandonment-n', 'after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n', '1'],
 ['abandonment-n', 'as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n', '1'],
 ['cake-n', 'against+n-the+vg-restv', '1'],
 ['cake-n', 'as+n-a+vd-require-v', '1'],
 ['cake-n', 'as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v', '1'],
 ['cake-n', 'as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n', '2'],
 ['dog-n', 'as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v', '7'],
 ['dog-n', 'as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n', '5']]

In [24]: df = pandas.DataFrame(split_lines, columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
            Col1                           Col2 Col3
0  abandonment-n           about+n-the+v-know-v    1
1  abandonment-n  above+ns-j+vn-pass-continue-v    1
2  abandonment-n       after+n-the+n-a-j-stop-n    1
3  abandonment-n            as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n    1
4         cake-n         against+n-the+vg-restv    1
5         cake-n            as+n-a+vd-require-v    1
6         cake-n           as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    1
7         cake-n            as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n    2
8          dog-n           as+n-a-j+vg-up-use-v    7
9          dog-n            as+n-the+ns-j-aid-n    5

In [26]: df.groupby("Col1").apply(lambda x: (x.Col3.values[None,:],))
Out[26]:
Col1
abandonment-n    (array([[1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=object),)
cake-n           (array([[1, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=object),)
dog-n                  (array([[7, 5]], dtype=object),)

In [27]: n_rows = len(df.Col1.unique())

In [28]: n_cols = len(df.Col2.unique())

In [29]: n_rows, n_cols
Out[29]: (3, 7)
```

Comment: not for homework, wish I was still in school :P I'm checking out the `count_vectorizer`, seems like it may be of some help...

Comment: PS. not really what I need as it seems to create counts based on the input data. I have already calculated that. My problem is really just reformatting the data... But, if one needs to calculate their semantic/space populate matrices with weights or boolean values - it is a good tool.

Comment: I added an approach using Pandas.DataFrame for the re-formatting task. I don't know if it will be helpful with a multi-GB file, unless you can read it in in chunks and have a script that iterates over the chunks and stores out intermediate sparse representations. When you get the `numpy.ndarray` that contains lists, each of which contains another `ndarray` with the actual sparse row info, you would need to parse that into an actual `scipy.sparse` matrix, and then use the `sparse.vstack` command to concatenate the sparse rows from each chunk.

Comment: After solving the attribute error, I seemed to come across a panda-specific error which I am not sure how to handle:  `    df.groupby("Col1").apply(lambda x: (x.Col3.values[None,:],))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
` I am trying this using python2.7 (correct)?

Comment: This is not a pandas error. This is telling you that your object `df` is *not* a pandas DataFrame but is instead just a regular `list`. Did you call the DataFrame constructor?

Comment: I have. I honestly have no idea where the problem is :s

Comment: If you post more code at the bottom of your original question, I can try to help further. But just seeing that list error doesn't allow me to help much.